# StackSalesforce twitter account not tweeting

Tags: feature-request, bug

I follow [StackSalesforce](https://twitter.com/StackSalesforce) on Twitter religiously, but since last few days haven't seen any of the SFSE tweets, is the Integration broken?

The last tweet was on May 16 2019.

Comment: Looks like it just started again.  I'm guessing it's not a coincidence, but I'm not sure how it was fixed or by whom.